# Websocket error using Vaadin on AWS with load balancer and Push enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, vaadin, load-balancing, vaadin-flow

I'm getting this error when I am enabling load balancing on AWS elasticbeanstalk.

The Vaadin app is running regularly without a load balancer.

Any idea on how to solve this?

```
[Error] WebSocket connection to 'ws://console3.myapp.it/?v-r=push&v-uiId=1&v-pushId=3189d42a-dac5-4c4b-a196-98bf3fdd337e&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.3.2.vaadin1-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&Content-Type=application/json;%20charset=UTF-8&X-atmo-protocol=true' failed: Unexpected response code: 200
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway) (console3.myapp.it, line 0)
[Error] Unhandled Promise rejection: – "Client is resynchronizing" – "; Zone:" – "<root>" – "; Task:" – "XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener:readystatechange" – "; Value:" (2)
Error: Client is resynchronizing(funzione anonima) — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:792:92forEachtw — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:792qv — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:702Ev — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:1035:26387d — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:678forEachrv — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:690Gr — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:1031:165Hr — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:1012:404Wt — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:1035:24288uC — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:1035:37400(funzione anonima) — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:614sb — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:440vb — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:896(funzione anonima) — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:622L — vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1696413(funzione anonima) — vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1680927(funzione anonima) — vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1686825v — vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1699889b — vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1700114
    (funzione anonima) (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1689290)
    d (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1689710)
    t (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1689613)
    (funzione anonima) (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1689630)
    g (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1688076)
    (funzione anonima) (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1686848)
    v (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1699889)
    b (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1700114)
[Error] Unhandled Promise rejection: – "Client is resynchronizing" – "; Zone:" – "<root>" – "; Task:" – "XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener:readystatechange" – "; Value:" (2)
Error: Client is resynchronizing(funzione anonima) — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:792:92forEachtw — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:792qv — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:702Ev — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:1035:26387d — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:678forEachrv — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:690Gr — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:1031:165Hr — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:1012:404Wt — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:1035:24288uC — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:1035:37400(funzione anonima) — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:614sb — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:440vb — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:896(funzione anonima) — client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js:622L — vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1696413(funzione anonima) — vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1680927(funzione anonima) — vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1686825v — vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1699889b — vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1700114
    (funzione anonima) (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1689290)
    d (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1689710)
    t (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1689613)
    (funzione anonima) (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1689630)
    g (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1688076)
    (funzione anonima) (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1686848)
    v (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1699889)
    b (vaadin-bundle-7bcbd4c63d030f328f20.cache.js:4928:1700114)
```

Comment: You get 502, which indicates that possibly load balancer is not configured to route WebSocket connection to server correctly. You app did not fall back to long polling, so it worked when started. Perhaps timeout issue. Or sticky sessions not enabled. You could test @Push(transport = Transport.LONG_POLLING) and see what happens then. Does it work longer. If you see odd errors with that too, check sticky sessions setting.

Comment: Hi Tatu, thanks for the help, Yes, with long polling the app is running well.

May be the problem as you set is on the sticky session configuration.
Just enabling Sticky Session does not solve the issue.

Comment: Solved installing Application Load Balancer instead of Classic load balancer

Answer (score 2):

The classic load Balancer does not support Websocket.

Installing Application Load Balancer instead of Classic load balancer will solve the problem.

See https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/features/?nc1=h_ls